# Is there a way to have a "master list" of classes, and use that list within those classes?

Tags: python

I have a series of Python modules. Each one contains a class with a name matching its directory:

```
a/__init__.py
a/aa/__init__.py
a/ab/__init__.py
b/ba/__init__.py
b/bb/__init__.py
c/ca/__init__.py
c/ca/caa/__init__.py
utils/__init__.py
```

I have a free variable and function that maps the class in each module to a string, in `utils/__init__.py`:

```py
import a
import a.aa
import a.ab
import b
import b.ba
import b.bb
import c
import c.ca
import c.ca.caa

MAPPING = {
  "Foobar": a.A,
  "Apple": a.aa.Aa,
  "Banana": a.ab.Ab,
  "Clementine": b.ba.Ba,
  "Granola": b.B,
  "Donut": b.bb.Bb,
  "Hashbrowns": c.C,
  "Egg": c.ca.Ca,
  "Furniture": c.ca.caa.Caa,
}

def find_class(s):
  return MAPPING[s]
```

However, I would like to use this function inside some of these classes. For example, `b/ba/__init__.py` may contain the following:

```py
import utils

class Ba():
  def mycall(self, s):
    return utils.find_class(s)
```

This causes an issue trying to import that class:

```
Python 3.9.6 (default, Jun 29 2021, 05:25:02)
>>> from b.ba import Ba
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".../python3imports/b/ba/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import utils
  File ".../python3imports/utils/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    "Clementine": b.ba.Ba,
AttributeError: module 'b' has no attribute 'ba'
>>>
```

Is there a way to have a "master list" of classes, and use that list within those classes?

Comment: "Is there a way to have a "master list" of classes, and use that list within those classes?" Your problem has fundamentally nothing to do with any of that. The problem you have is a circular dependency between your *modules*. There are various ways to solve that. One way would be to put everything inside one module (note, generally having one class per module is not a common pattern in Python). Another is putting the import inside that method

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hacky but this solution is functional:

```py
MAPPING = {}


def _make_mapping(m):
    import a
    import a.aa
    import a.ab
    import b
    import b.ba
    import b.bb
    import c
    import c.ca
    import c.ca.caa

    m["Foobar"] = a.A
    m["Apple"] = a.aa.Aa
    m["Banana"] = a.ab.Ab
    m["Clementine"] = b.ba.Ba
    m["Granola"] = b.B
    m["Donut"] = b.bb.Bb
    m["Hashbrowns"] = c.C
    m["Egg"] = c.ca.Ca
    m["Furniture"] = c.ca.caa.Caa


def find_class(s):
  if not MAPPING:
    _make_mapping(MAPPING)
  return MAPPING[s]
```

This prevents any class imports from being attempted until `find_class` is run for the first time, determines that `MAPPING` is empty, and populates it. In this way, importing `utils` in one of the listed classes keeps a circular import from occurring.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.